# Confusion about correlation and Vif

Tags: correlation, variance-inflation-factor

The correlation matrix of my data set shows that two variables are highly correlated with a correlation value of 0.84. Vif of variable1 is 4.469 and variable2 is 4.347. Will this create a problem?. Can I consider them for my study?.

Comment: Create a problem on what aspects?

Comment: Whether this multicollinearity is an issue depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Hence User1865345's question.

Comment: Create problems related to the trustworthiness of the coefficients and p values for these two variables in the regression model. These two variables are the main predictors in the model.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment you say you are interested in the effect on coefficients and p values.

For the VIF, there are various guidelines. Some people say "above 3", some "above 4" and some give higher values. I'd say you definitely want to investigate it.  R used to have a package called `perturb` which I liked for this purpose; it has been removed from CRAN (I am not sure why) and `??perturb` does not find anything. Basically, it added random noise to the data and re-ran the regression, multiple times. You could also look at the condition indexes.

Also, for interpretation, remember that, when you have two (or more) variables in a regression, all the parameter estimates are controlling for the other variables. This may or may not be what you want. The "effect" of one variable after controlling for 70% of its variance may be hard to interpret (or it might not).

If you tell us what the variables are, someone here may be able to give more advice.

Comment: Re "definitely want to investigate it": Why?  Since we don't even know what the OP's objectives are and we have no information about how many variables or observations are involved, this recommendation is premature at best.

Comment: Read her comment where she says she is interested in the coefficients and p values and that these are the two main variables. (Yes, she should have put that in the questiion).

Comment: I did read that comment and took it into account.